# How to ignore Retrofit answer when using Observables?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an API call like:

```
@GET("/something")
Observable<MyType> myCall();
```

I'd like to use this call, but I do not want the response to get serialized into MyType. I just would like the thing to run and be done with it. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Observable<Void>`?

Comment: Interesting, let me check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Observable, use a class that was written specifically for that case called Completable which has only onCompleted() and onError() and no onNext() callback which is what you want here.

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Completable.html